# Add C++11 support in each Qt Creator project

Tags: c++, c++11, qt-creator, qmake

I've been using Qt Creator lately, and I find myself editing the .pro file with `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11` quite frequently.

Can I somehow modify the new project wizard to automatically add that build setting?

I'm using Qt Creator 2.7.0.

Comment: You can also use CONFIG += c++11 instead of using QMAKE_CXXFLAGS, just in-case that helps.

Comment: @Merlin069 - In Linux using QT I still need to use the QMAKE_CXXFLAGS or I get the "C++0x support is still experimental" warnings and errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the files the wizards are using in the following directory:

> C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\Tools\QtCreator\share\qtcreator\templates\wizards

(As you can see I am using Qt 5.0.2 on Windows so the given path might be a little different on your computer if you are using another Qt version or another operating system.)

Comment: Thanks, the relevant project file was `/usr/share/qtcreator/templates/wizards/plaincppapp/project.pro` in my  Debian machine. Going to mark as accepted, though I hope there's a better solution (which will work after updates too).